# GET request instead of DELETE?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest

Using the code shown below, I can't delete a student because when I click the delete button, it throws a Method Not Allowed error (status=405)

I found out that many people use GET request instead of DELETE to manage this, but isn't it a bad practice? I just only want to delete the student with that id and stay at the same page (I'll manage delete validations later after I fix this). Why does the same code work with GetMapping but not with DeleteMapping?

*In studentController*

```
@DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteStudent(@PathVariable Long id) {
        this.studentService.deleteStudent(id);

        return "redirect:/students";
    }
```

*In students.html*

`<a th:href="@{'/students/delete/' + ${student.id}}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>`

Comment: A link is always a GET request, heck the browser, with forms only supports GET/POST. Either use a hidden field which contains the actual method (and use a POST to send the form) or use an javascript submit and set the proper method.

Answer (score 1):

As M. Deinum said in comments, with html `<a href` you're doing http GET request. With html `form` you can do http GET or POST requests. So in your case changing `@DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")` to `@PostMapping("/delete/{id}")` and using html `<form method="post"` kind of makes sense.

If you want to use http DELETE, you will have to use javascript.